# How to return values separated by comma from array?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular7, angular-directive, angular-components

I work on angular 7 I face Issue: I can't separate returned values of ZCO by comma from OriginCountry.

Origin Country is an array of an object I need to collect property ZCO from it

separated by a comma when it has multiple values so How to do that?

on component.ts

```js
OriginCountry:any[]=[];  
this.OriginCountry = this.partDetailsService.currentData.OriginCountry;  
console.log("country origion" + JSON.stringify(this.OriginCountry) )
```

data returned from OriginCountry as below :

```
[
  { CO: "zx", ZCO: "China", InfSrc: "FMD", TP: "Factory" },
  { CO: "zy", ZCO: "Japan", InfSrc: "FMD", TP: "Factory" }
];
```

ON Component.html

```html
<div *ngFor="let country of OriginCountry">
  {{country.ZCO}}
</div>
```

Expected Result to be :

```
Japan,China
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other solution, this relies on `reduce`

```js
const csv = [
             {"CO":"zx","ZCO":"China","InfSrc":"FMD","TP":"Factory"}, 
             {"CO":"zy","ZCO":"Japan","InfSrc":"FMD","TP":"Factory"}
            ]
            .reduce((ZCOs, co) => [...ZCOs, co.ZCO], []).join(', ');
            
console.log(csv);
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't even need `ngFor` for that.

```
const csv = [
             {"CO":"zx","ZCO":"China","InfSrc":"FMD","TP":"Factory"}, 
             {"CO":"zy","ZCO":"Japan","InfSrc":"FMD","TP":"Factory"}
            ]
            .map(({ZCO}) => ZCO).join();
```

And then:

```
<div>
  {{csv}}
</div>
```